# Cron is not running in openhost

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I set new cron in my openhost admin panel using

`curl http://www.example.net.nz/sendmail.php` but its not working.

and my cron setting is below.

[image]

Please suggest me some idea what can i do so my cron is run properly.

I also read this but there is not any description regarding cron command [openhost support link](https://support.webhost.co.nz/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&group=openhost&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=63&nav=0,25).

Above command is properly in my WHM server unfortunately it not working in Openhost server.

Comment: May be try and see something like this works : `php /path/to/sendmail.php` or `php /path/to/sendmail.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `/usr/bin/php`  and path to file on server like `/var/www/project/a.php`